# Create time range table, or fill in empty dates in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, date, informix

How can a SELECT, which includes dates, that might miss some values be padded, to include all dates:

```
01.01.1970 | a
02.01.1970 | b
04.01.1970 | c
...
30.01.1970 | c
```

should become:

```
01.01.1970 | a
02.01.1970 | b
03.01.1970 | 
04.01.1970 | c
...
30.01.1970 | c
```

I could create a temporary table, which contains all dates, and then join the results. This feels clumsy.

I don't have access to scripting functionalities. Only the builtin functions. Informix version is 11.5.

EDIT: Query, which I use:

```
SELECT t.create_date, t.content
  FROM testdata t
 WHERE YEAR(t.create_date) = 1970
   AND MONTH(t.create_date) = 1
;
```

or this

```
SELECT t.create_date, t.content
  FROM testdata t
 WHERE YEAR(t.create_date) = 1970
;
```

Comment: Can you edit a question and share your current query with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might feel clumsy, but a Date Table (in Data Warehousing terms a 'Date Dimension') is the only sane way to do it.

A table that contains every date from 1900 to 2050 is only going to run to 55000 rows, and will no doubt have a unique index on the date field. Assuming this table has no other columns, it will fit in a few hundred pages. It's trivial to create it once and forget about it.

Lajos Arpad's solution is elegant in its own way and probably works, but you still have to decide the range of years it will support, and run all those nested queries every time you need to do this. It's *highly* unlikely that dynamically creating this table every time you need it is going to be more efficient than just building it once. Premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that.

Over time, you may find other uses for your Date Dimension. A flag field to record whether that day is a business day or not is a common one.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a record for all your dates, so you could generate the data you need to have `union`ing with your data you have, `group` them by `create_date` and selecting the biggest `content`.

```
select create_date, max(content) from
((SELECT t.create_date as create_date, t.content as content
  FROM testdata t
 WHERE YEAR(t.create_date) = 1970
   AND MONTH(t.create_date) = 1)
union
(select '01.01.1970' as create_date, '' as content
union
select '01.02.1970' as create_date, '' as content
union
select '01.03.1970' as _create_date, '' as content
union
select '01.04.1970' as create_date, '' as content)) temp
group by temp.create_date
;
```

EDIT: A more general solution:

```
    select create_date, max(content) from
    ((SELECT t.create_date as create_date, t.content as content
      FROM testdata t
     WHERE YEAR(t.create_date) = 1970
       AND MONTH(t.create_date) = 1)
    union
    (select concat('01-', concat(concat(month.m, '-'), year.y)) as create_date, ''
from
(select 1970 as y
union
select 1971 as y
union
select 1972 as y) year,
(select '01' as m
union
select '02' as m
union
select '03' as m
union
select '04' as m
union 
select '05' as m
union
select '06' as m
union
select '07' as m
union
select '08' as m
union
select '09' as m
union
select '10' as m
union
select '11' as m
union
select '12' as m) month)) temp
    group by temp.create_date
    ;
```

This one handles 1970, 1971 and 1972 but nothing stops you from handling different date sets.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm looking for a dynamic way to solve the problem. I can't add every possible date to the query. I added dots to my question, to show that the result of my query is larger.

Comment: @Kiril, I have edited my answer, maybe the newer version is more helpful.